# How do I scrape only the first column and href link of this websites HTML table into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

[Website in question](http://www.annualreports.com/Companies?search=). I want to **scrape** that table in the middle and just want the first column (the Company name) plus its href link.

For example here, I just want to **scrape** all the data between the first `<td> </td>` and ignore the rest of the three `<td>` values. Then create one Column with the company name (1-800-FLOWERS.COM in this case) and then a second Column with the href link (/Company/1-800-flowerscom)

[image: Image of HTML]

What I've done so far:

```
url = "http://www.annualreports.com/Companies?search="
html = request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company', 'Href'])

tables = soup.findChildren('table')
my_table = tables[0]
rows = my_table.findChildren(['th', 'tr'])

for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        value = cell.string
        print(value)
```

This successfully extracts *all* the `<td>` tags successfully in this format:

[image: Print statement2]

Now would the most efficient way to fill my df column be to change my second nested loop to step 4 and to take in 1 value and then ignore the next 3? That seems really convoluted to me, is there a better way where I can do all of this directly from the source? That is, extract only the first `<td>` value from all the `<tr>`s and then separate the company name and href value into two different columns (for the entire table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to restrict to first column (`td`). As the nodes have both the `href` of interest and the text you can use a tuple within the list comprehension to retrieve both from same node then rely on pandas at end to handle the columns. I'm using bs4 4.7.1. Not sure at which version this started being supported but you really want the latest bs4 possible due to the improvements made.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://www.annualreports.com/Companies?search=')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
df = pd.DataFrame([(i.text, 'http://www.annualreports.com' + i['href']) for i in soup.select('tbody td:nth-of-type(1) a')], columns = ['Company','Link'])
print(df)
```

---

Some explanation:

```
soup.select('tbody td:nth-of-type(1) a')
```

selects all the child `a` tags within the first column (`td`). `tbody` is there to ensure right table is worked with. 
`tbody,td` and `a` are [type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) and select based on tag, whereas the spaces in between are [descendant combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), meaning the element to be matched on the right is a child of the element to be matched on the left.

`select` returns a list.

The list comprehension

```
[(i.text, 'http://www.annualreports.com' + i['href']) for i in soup.select('tbody td:nth-of-type(1) a')]
```

could be re-written as:

```
for i in soup.select('tbody td:nth-of-type(1) a'):
    (i.text, 'http://www.annualreports.com' + i['href']) #tuple that is then added to a final list
```

As you iterate over each `a` tag in the list returned by `select`; the current node (`a` tag) has both the title, as its `.text` 
property, and the `href` as an attribute. The attribute value can be accessed as shown. The `'http://www.annualreports.com'` prefix is added to make the links complete (as otherwise they are relative and lack protocol and domain).

The list is passed to pandas where the list of tuples (let's call it `the_list` as per example) is unpacked into the two columns. The `columns` argument of `pd.DataFrame` is used to name the columns in the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(the_list , columns = ['Company','Link'])  # the_list being the result of the list comprehension
```

Comment: Could you please explain the second last line in a little more detail? I get it whats its doing overall but going left to right word by word its not all making that much sense to me. Also thank you so so much for that code, its much simpler than what I was thinking of doing; I hadn't heard of nth-of-type before

Comment: Some more info added for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That makes sense, though Im still not sure if Ill be able to write something like that just by myself  :(